# Pip can't install packages without permission on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have venv located at /usr/local/<venv_name> and when I use `pip install <package>`(of course I did activate venv) it can't install it because ubuntu denies permission to create folder in this directory, but if I write `sudo pip install <package>` it installs it not to my venv, but to my main python. I found "solution", as I just created venv in ~/ directory(it doesn't request for sudo, so `pip install <package>` works as it must). Can I somehow create venv at /usr/local/ and install packages to this venv?

Comment: Why do you want to create the virtualenv directory in `/usr/local`? It is usually not writable by normal users and I'm pretty sure Ubuntu warns you if you try to modify its permissions. And I doubt you want to, say, have a virtualenv that can only be modified while you have root-level permissions.

Comment: @wkl Well I'm not really need to create venv in that directory, but I'm just want to find out why is it works like that and how to fix that

Comment: The explanation for what you're seeing is that when you activate the virtualenv, it modifies your environment settings (like putting the `venv` into your `PATH`). When you run `sudo` to do anything like `pip install`, the `sudo` ignores pretty much all environment settings from the user that invoked `sudo` - this is a standard security measure for sudo itself. You _can_ override this with `sudo -E`, which makes `sudo` preserve the environment from the invoking user - this does need to be configured in the `/etc/sudoers` file for what you want to keep.